# Alternative for UIBezierPath in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

I have used UIBezierPath for animating a image in a curved path, but UIBezierPath is supported for iOS 3.2 or later, I need to support my app for 3.0 how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, don't use `UIBezierPath`. Just create a `CGMutablePathRef` instead with the plain Core Graphics functions.